# Can JCL Parm value be referenced in SYSIN DD *(Instream data) using symbolic parameter?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

e.g. :

```
//JOBNAME PROC PARMS='XXXXX --clean' , ENV='DEV'
```

In above PROC, at the execution time, I want to pass ENV='TEST' and that value should get used in
ENVIRONMENT instream data shown below.

```
//STDENV   DD   *,SYMBOLS=JCLONLY   <-- signal to interpret JCL symbols in instream data  
ENVIRONMENT=&ENV                                                       
//*                                                                     
// PEND                                                                 
//
```

I know, we can use EXPORT SYMLIST=* & SYMBOLS= to modify instream data using SET keyword in JCL however I am not sure if we can use it for JCL Parameter value as ENV='test', please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. All you need to do is to place the statement

```
//       EXPORT  SYMLIST=ENV
```

anywhere *before* the statement executing the procedure. Additionally, code the paramaeter `SYMBOLS=JCLONLY` on all `//anyname DD *` statements you want the symbolic to be resolved.

If you want to enable *all* JCL symbolics for resolution, code `SYMLIST=*` instead. If you want to enable this *anywhere* in the job, place the `EXPORT` statement just after the `//JOB` statement.